# Is there any alternate of ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION permission to save images, seems it now comes with photo picker in android 14?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-storage, android-14

My app captures photos through/inside the app only, and saves it to `\pictures\MyAppFolder`. The app doesn't read/required to read any existing images, as it's not showing any image inside the app. So, to save images to phone storage I use `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission (for api > 28).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
```

When I try to migrate the app to android 14, where upon runtime permission for `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION`, it shows a prompt with photo picker (attached image). Which seems not ideal for my case  *(as my app doesn't fall in a category which gives an option to upload image to any server/service or make any use of the existing images, like for editing)*  to give a choice to pick/request access to any image.

[Screenshot of the prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNC47.jpg)

As the [official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED) says that with `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` request, a permission named `READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED` will automatically added to an app's manifest which brings up the prompt/behavior for android 14. Thus it seems an expected behavior with android 14 (targetSDK 34)

So, now I am looking for any alternate permission which applies for my use case. Since it will be very confusing for the user to understand what and why any image they need to select from the prompt? And yes I believe I would not require `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission here. Also Google won't allow the same, as it won't fall to the appropriate use case.

Comment: Use `MediaStore` to store media. I cover that [here](https://commonsware.com/Q/pages/chap-media-004) as part of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Q).

Comment: `Is there any alternate of ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION permission to save images, ...` ? You do not need that permission to save images.

Comment: This READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED is from the devil but you also do not need it to save images or let the user select an image file.

Comment: `am looking for any alternate permission which applies for my use case.` Sorry, your use case keeps unclear to me.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the suggestion/link. Would like to know what runtime permission (and/or inside manifest) I will require with `MediaStore` .  Also would it work in android 14 without the photo picker option?

Comment: @blackapps If you see my use case it's quite simple: I capture images and save it to storage. Whereas I am not providing any interface/option to view or use the image to edit or upload it to anywhere.

The only problem is with `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` with android 14 is- with that it's showing the user an option to select photos from their gallery which can be confusing that, why I need to select any picture, the app should automatically save it when required? Right?
MediaStore option looks interesting will try that out.

Comment: @ItsVicky: `MediaStore` does not require a runtime permission, last I checked. "Also would it work in android 14 without the photo picker option?" -- sorry, but I do not know what you mean by this. You are not picking media; you are writing media. Writing media does not involve a photo picker.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I tried that, yes it doesn't require any permission (also read the same in your book link provided) and also worked with android 14. I was also wondering that why the app would show a photo picker option in my use case. 
Thank you very much, could you please update your comment to answer so that I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I recommend that you supply your own answer, with the details of the solution that you went with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @CommonsWare to use `MediaStore` with this [link](https://commonsware.com/Q/pages/chap-media-004).
I found I was already having a method using `MediaStore` for android 10 and above. But I had also used `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission which was not required in my case, as I was just storing the image not reading them or any other images.

So, I just removed the `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission and it worked for android 14 as well, without any image picker option in permission request prompt.
[Official Document](https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics#TaskPath) covering the same.